# 3dsp BlueW2310U bluetooth/wireless combo has no driver support in 12.04 LTS

Tags: drivers

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kernel 3.2.9-26-generic) on a touchpad with a 3dsp BlueW2310U bluetooth/wireless combo device internally installed.  It does not work because the release does not include the drivers.

Searching the web I have discovered that the manufacturer's web site is "off the air" so it does not look like I can get the driver source from them.  I have also discovered that Ubuntu version 10.04 (kernel 2.6.32) did have support.

Is there some way to get support added back into the 12.04 release and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: 3dsp drivers has never had proper Linux support. The company used to release builds in 2010 that would work on outdated kernel version, but then stopped doing even that. Cuurently, there is no known way to get support.

Answer (score 1):

Patched 3DSP USB driver (tested on Ubuntu 12.04 with network manager)

NOTES: This driver was tested to be working fine with Wifi. BT was not tested yet. ALso, please check and make sure your device appears as USB device as in lsusb command.

https://github.com/binghuawu/3dsp

Answer (score 0):

Drivers old http://www.stk.com.tw/product-01.asp?Product_Type=58 mod drivers https://github.com/reyiyo/3dsp/ work in 2.6.38-10. There is source code yet some parts are binary and have not specified the type of license. It could send an email asking them to delivery of measured Syntek driver or asking for the license type of driver's license to supporting developer could include some or modify the kernel.